# Convert exponential number to decimal in php

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal

I have a floating point number in exponential format i.e. `4.1595246940817E-17` and I want to convert it into decimal number like 2.99 etc.

Any help will be appreciated.

`format_number()` `sprintf()` don't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Exponential or decimal are just ways of showing a human-readable form of the number.

I am not really sure of what you want..

Comment: I can't figure out where 2.99 comes from (you might want to tell us what you _really_ expect), but are you expecting __number_format(4.1595246940817E-17, 2)__ to produce __4.15__? If it did, your calculations would be off by many orders of magnitude (the correct result would be __0.00__).

Comment: Yes I am expecting 4.1595246940817E-17 to produce 2.99. Here is my situation. Allocation Size: 65536 bytes = 65536/1024 = 64KB. Allocation units: 49107. Total size=  49107*64 = 3142848KB = 3069.18MB= 2.99GB

Comment: Here is my code <pre><code><?php 
$au = 65536; //allocation unit size ib bytes
$auk = $au / 1024; //Allocation unit size in KB

$totalSize = (49107*$auk)/(1024*1024);

echo $totalSize;
?></code></pre> This produces 2.99 but if I get realtime values from registry/snmp trap etc.. then it produces 4.1595246940817E-17.

Comment: That's completely different from your question, then. Try the solutions given by ajreal and Russell Dias, below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a better math extension like BC [Math, GMP...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php) to handle the more precise precision.

Limitation of [floating number](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) & [integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Comment: Yes I am expecting 4.1595246940817E-17 to produce 2.99. Here is my situation. Allocation Size: 65536 bytes = 65536/1024 = 64KB. Allocation units: 49107. Total size=  49107*64 = 3142848KB = 3069.18MB= 2.99GB

Comment: @user544836 - does it a maths ? If so, try the math extension, If **NOT** ... not sure what can be done

Comment: @Saqib - ic, you should does this instead `php -r "echo 49107*64/1024/1024;"`, preset the Gb instead of let it overflow...

Answer (score 1):

Using the [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php) library you can `bcscale()` the numbers to a predetermined decimal, which sets the parameter for future calculations that require arithmetic precision.

```
bcscale(3);
echo bcdiv('105', '6.55957'); // 16.007
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the decimal point ($x is your number):

```
$strfloat = strtolower((string)($x));
$nodec = str_replace(".", "", $x);
```

Then extract the exponential part.

```
list($num, $exp) = explode("e", $nodec);
$exp = intval($exp);
```

Then you have the decimal, and the number, so you can format it:

```
if($exp < 0) return "0." . ("0" * -($exp + 1)) . $num;
if($exp == 0) return (string)$x;
if($exp > 0) return $num . ("0" * $exp);
```

This doesn't add precision though, just extra zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php), as suggested by ajreal and Russell Dias:

```
$au = 65536; 
$auk = bcdiv($au, 1024);
$totalSize = bcdiv(bcmul(49107, $auk), bcpow(1024, 2), 2); 
echo $totalSize . "\n"; 

// echos 2.99
```