# Convert exponential to a whole number in PHP

Tags: php, exponential

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert exponential number to decimal in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461444/convert-exponential-number-to-decimal-in-php)

Is there a way to convert an exponential number to a whole number in PHP using built in functions? A format function?

1.2378147769392E+14 to 123781477693917

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#4461444](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461444/convert-exponential-number-to-decimal-in-php)

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? That are both the exact same number, so no conversion will occur in any case.

Comment: what i get is a string with the exponential format, i would like the value returned to be a decimal format

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
number_format(1.2378147769392E+14,0,'','')
```

However, for working with large numbers, if you want to keep precision, you should look into [BCMath extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

Comment: rtrim(sprintf("%.20f", $const1), "0");