# How do I make php display the zeros instead of -7?

Tags: php

Since I'm a beginner in `PHP` I can't figure it out how I should make my calculator display the zeros instead of -x at the end?

```
<?php
$intValue = 0;
$arrResult = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://preev.com/pulse/units:btc+usd/sources:bitfinex+bitstamp+btce'), true);
foreach($arrResult['btc']['usd'] as $key => $index){
    $intValue = $intValue + $arrResult['btc']['usd'][$key]['last'];
}
echo ($intValue / 3);
$val1 = 1;
$value001usd = $val1 / $intValue / 3 / 1000;
echo "  0.001 USD Equals to $value001usd BTC";
?>
```

It outputs the result at the time of this post as: `402.31333333333 0.001 USD Equals to 2.7618053369126E-7 BTC`

Now I need it to be `" 402.31333333333 0.001 USD Equals to 0.000002761 BTC"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to properly format the value with the number of decimals you need:

```
$valueBTC = $val1 / $intValue / 3 / 1000;
$textBTC  = number_format($valueBTC, 10);
echo("  0.001 USD Equals to $textBTC BTC\n");
```

Comment: Copied Answer from my comment. LOL i have told you in my comment before his answer and you approved :P @J.Doe

Comment: @K.Uzair I didn't even read the comments on your answer. I down-voted it and added my comment to explain why. And btw, the "solution" you posted in the comment doesn't answer the question. I can tell you without bothering to test it that `number_format($value001usd,0,'','') == '0'`.

Answer (score -2):

You Can Actually round your output number to whatever length you want.
Here is an example 
echo round(1.9558334534534, 5);  // Outputs  1.95583

Here is the link for php function where you can get extra help

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: What about the zeros that need to be displayed instead of -7 at the end?

Comment: try using number format function. number_format($value001usd,0,'','') in your case. Hope it will solve your problem. you may look on this answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964059/convert-exponential-to-a-whole-number-in-php

Comment: Rounding doesn't change the value type. The value returned by `round()` is a double, `echo()` displays using the best format to show as much information (in this case decimals) it can. And for this number, the scientific format is the best.