# Convert exponential number presented as string to a decimal

Tags: php

Let's suppose I have a **string** that contains "7.2769482308e+01" (this number came from 3rd party software, I cannot control the format).

What is the cheapest way to convert it into decimal `72.769482308`?

The only solution I can think of is to split decimal + exponential part and use multiplication. But may be there some built it function to do the same?

**NOTE**: Guys, yes, I've read [Convert exponential to a whole number in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964059/convert-exponential-to-a-whole-number-in-php) and [Convert exponential number to decimal in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461444/convert-exponential-number-to-decimal-in-php). And that questions are irrelevant, since they already have a number, but I have a **string**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about a simple cast to a float value ?

```
$string = "7.2769482308e+01";
$float  = (float) $string;
```

Comment: Lol, surprisingly simple... Never know that php can recognize string exponential format in casting. Is this behaviour documented?

Comment: @zerkms Yeah. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion and http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: Yes, something exists in documentation: http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: @zerkms: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: Documented at http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion with the example of "-1.3e3"

Comment: @hsz: definitely not on that juggling page though ;-)

Answer (score 13):

I had success using `number_format(1.2378147769392E+14, 0, '', '')` which was originally provided by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4964120/213987).

This also works when the value is a string, like so: `number_format("1.2378147769392E+14", 0, '', '')`.  Go ahead, give it a try.

Comment: Ouch, harsh words... Have you even tried this? Because this works both when the value is and is not a string.

Comment: any reason to perfer over a solution that almost twice shorter and more readable: `(float) $string` ? PS: they are not harsh, it wasn't an answer in its initial edition PPS: `number_format` accepts the number as a first argument so the string is being converted implicitly PPPS: the result is a string, so another conversion need to be performed to get the decimal/float

Comment: somehow $float  = (float) $string; is twice shorter than $float = number_format($string, 0, '', '').. lol.. OP had a bit too much coffee I think. Good answer btw! Just upvoted

Answer (score 1):

Making this dynamic with respect to no. of digits after `E` would be much better.

Grab those digit precisions using `explode` and use [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to format them.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function getFormattedDecimal($str){
    $precision = explode("e", strtolower($str));
    $precision = substr($precision[1], 1); // remove + and - operators
    return sprintf("%.".$precision."f", $str);
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/3hoZu)

**Note:** `sprintf` may round decimal places depending upon the decimal style.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very cheap one: `$float = "7.2769482308e+01" + 0;`