# Exponential number showing different behavior on different servers

Tags: php, mysql

My question reflects to old question with little change. I am fetching values from MySQL db table datatype for the field is varchar(32) & it stores values like:

```
1.497e-05 and so on.
```

and I want to show `1.497e-05 as 0.00001497`

i tried as mentioned here [Convert exponential number presented as string to a decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340283/convert-exponential-number-presented-as-string-to-a-decimal) but fail.

One thing more i am trying to insert `0.00001497` to table but it stores as `1.497e-05` it though field datatype is varchar(32)

Comment: No, it almost certainly writes the correct value; but MS Excel formats it as scientific.... open the file in a text editor to verify

Comment: nop in notpad it is showing 497e-05

Comment: So how are you writing the file? Are you casting these varchars to float? If so, don't

Comment: no i just pic values from table and push on file cell.

Comment: what if the value was `1.497e-15` you want `0.000000000000001497` ?

Comment: File cell? You're using an array of values returned from MySQL and fputcsv() to write to file?

Comment: One thing more i am trying to insert `0.00001497` to table but it stores as `1.497e-05` it though field datatype is varchar(32). If it is fixed then I am sure there will be no issue to store in csv.

Comment: How are you opening the csv? excel or notepad? excel autodisplays float numbers in exponential notation. There is no way that a varchar value saved as "0.00001497" gets converted into exponential notation without tampering. Some code would be nice