# convert scientific notation number into normal number by php?

Tags: php, csv

I would like to say first : [Convert exponential number presented as string to a decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340283/convert-exponential-number-presented-as-string-to-a-decimal)  Question is not relevant to mine.

I am trying to batch upload(csv file data). Here some mobile number have scientific notation. [image]

I can convert this into text format in csv files. But it is so much pathetic to do for 1000 data. I tried to read data as it as:

```
$formatted = number_format($mobileNoFromCsvFile, 0, '.', ''); 

echo $mobileNoFromCsvFile; print 8.80168E+12 but `echo  $formatted;` print print 8801680000000 which mean   $mobileNoFromCsvFile contains 8.80168x10^-12. all digits after 880168 are truncated. Anyone have such experience to solve this issue.
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert exponential number presented as string to a decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340283/convert-exponential-number-presented-as-string-to-a-decimal)

Comment: Sorry this question is not relevant to me. My problem is not only converting floating data but also getting data from file and convert by php