# convert a scientific notation/exponential number

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a scientific notation/exponential number.

For example :

I get from a API request this number : 4.96E-6

I want to convert it to his normal value 0.00000496.

I searched on the web and tryed a few codes like

```
$awb = "4.96e-6"; // tried with and without quotes
$format = sprintf($awb, "%e");
var_dump($format);
```

it returns : string(7) "4.96E-6"

```
$awb = 4.96e-6;
$format = sscanf($awb, "%e");
var_dump($format);
```

Is returning :

```
array(1) { [0]=> float(4.96E-6) }
```

Please what should I do ?

Thank you

Comment: Is it 496 or 596?

Comment: @PatrickQ while I'm sure that this is a duplicate of something, the accepted answer on that is *awful*.

Comment: Do you want to convert this to a differently-formatted *string* for output, or to a *number* for calculations?

Comment: @Sammitch Yeah, I found what's probably a better one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340283/convert-exponential-number-presented-as-string-to-a-decimal) after I picked that. Can't retract and then vote again though, so figured I'd just live my original close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the number_format() function; e.g.

```
<?php
$awb = "4.96e-6";
print number_format($awb, 10);
?>
```

Will result in the output: 0.0000049600.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php