# How to convert Exponentials to Decimals in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point

I have a string like this:

```
  9.018E-14
```

Now I want to convert to this to the normal decimal numbers.

Comment: And what happened with your code? What do you think is wrong with it? What did you try to correct it?

Comment: You will need to compensate for `str_replace(".", "", $number)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461444/convert-exponential-number-to-decimal-in-php?rq=1

Comment: You mean floatval() doesn't work? or simply casting to float?

Comment: @suraj if your problem is solved, please accept the answer you deem appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Here is some PHP magic:

```
$stringval = "12e-3";
$numericval = 0 + $stringval;
```

From the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float.

If you need a more flexible format (e.g. extract four numbers from the same string), use `sscanf` like this:

```
$stringval = "12e-3";
$numericval = sscanf($stringval, "%f")[0];
echo $numericval;
```

Comment: There's even simpler methods: `$floatval = floatval($stringval);` or `$floatval = (float) $stringval;` but what are you wittering about integers for when this is clearly a float?

Comment: Simpler? They are just as simple, maybe longer to write (and a bit more explicit). But why downvote?

Comment: Downvoted because you're wittering on about integers, why are integers relevant?

Comment: The OP never said he/she wanted a float number as result. If the number can fit inside a integer, why avoid using it?

Comment: 9.018E-14 is a float unless you round it to an integer, losing all the precision... you've given an answer that is complex, unnecessary, and returns a result that bears no resemblence to the original number.... what value do you get from `$intval = 1 + $stringval;`? A result that's had 1 added to it.... where does OP say he wants to add a 1 to his value?

Comment: That was an example: I don't think the OP would bother asking if it was all about converting one number. Good point about the 1 (mistype, edited), but -1 on floating point: `1e2`  and `100` are equivalent and the associated value can be represented both by an integer and a floating point number. Read the paragraph I posted in the answer: the number is converted to floating point, unless it's integer and it fits inside the integer range: no loss, apart from the finite precision, but that cannot be avoided. I am aware that other answers are acceptable, but I don't see a reason for downvoting.

Comment: Perhaps if you modify the references to $intval because that's misleading

Answer (score 4):

[MyGeekPal](http://www.mygeekpal.com/how-to-convert-exponentials-to-decimals-in-php/) has a nice article on it.

Code:

```
<?php
$total_time = 2.8848648071289E-5;

echo exp2dec($total_time);

function exp2dec($number) {
    preg_match('/(.*)E-(.*)/', str_replace(".", "", $number), $matches);
    $num = "0.";
    while ($matches[2] > 0) {
        $num .= "0";
        $matches[2]--;
    }
    return $num . $matches[1];
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like the original code, which was also broken. Consider `28.848648071289E-5` (though I appreciate that this is a non-standard form)

Answer (score 2):

### If your input is a `float`

If you have `$number = 0.00023459` then printing this value in PHP will probably result in this exponential format. It doesn't mean the variable is *stored* that way; it's just an output artefact.

Use [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) to work around this and gain control over your numeric output.

---

### If your input is a `string`

Why the complexity?

```
$matches = Array();
if (preg_match('/(.*)E-(.*)/', $number, $matches)) {
   $number = $matches[1] * pow(10, -1*$matches[2]);
}
```

Though you can tighten up the regex a bit:

```
$matches = Array();
if (preg_match('/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)E(-?\d+)/i', $number, $matches)) {
   $number = (float)$matches[1] * pow(10, (int)$matches[2]);
}
```

#### [Live demo](http://ideone.com/5MA6I5)