# PHP file get contents returning float with e-5

Tags: php, json, decode, file-get-contents

I have written a little bit of code to return the value "lastPrice" from the json provided by http://csc.blockexp.info/ext/summary, but it is returning the value as 8.503E-5 instead of the desired lastPrice.

```
{"data":[{"difficulty":159.63461978,"supply":33494475.4445624,"hashrate":"11.2889","lastPrice":0.00008503,"connections":24,"blockcount":1136720}]}

$jsonCSC = file_get_contents('http://csc.blockexp.info/ext/summary');
$dataCSC = json_decode($jsonCSC,true);
print_r($dataCSC);
$priceCSC = $dataCSC["data"][0]["lastPrice"];
```

the array prints like so:

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [difficulty] => 110.1356266 [supply] => 33494245.423562 [hashrate] => 10.5306 [lastPrice] => 8.503E-5 [connections] => 24 [blockcount] => 1136696 ) ) )
```

As you can see lastPrice is not the last price from the file_get_contents link. I have no idea where the E-5 is coming from and why the value is being returned as 8.503 instead of the floating value any insight would be appreciated.

@enkrates pointed out that is is completely valid as a float with E-5!

Comment: The E can be short for `10^`. So 8.503*10^-5 would be 0.00008503 which probably isn't right to begin with.

Comment: See [this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HNDLxV) for an example of it being used as a (valid) number.

Comment: @JaredFarrish After some inspection anything after 7 decimal places is turned into the format #E-# but I need to have the 8 decimal places since it is a value. So if I do `$priceCSC / pow(10, -5) / 10000` it is returning it as 0.0008501 but I need it to be 0.00008501. Any thoughts? @iam-decoder that is actually the right answer!

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kaBzHO

Comment: @JaredFarrish Exactly what I needed thankyou very much!

Answer (score 2):

8.503E-5 is actually valid PHP syntax for a floating point number. See the [PHP documentation for floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) for more information and an example.

Comment: Is there any way besides doing math after I retrieve the value to return the value as is from the file_get_contents link?

Comment: It seems like converting a number in that format can be complicated. See [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461444/convert-exponential-number-to-decimal-in-php) for some ideas (warning: may involve PHP extensions).