# PHP: How do I can get data as string format from Excel data with scientific notation / exponential format?

Tags: php, phpexcel, exponential, scientific-notation, phpexcelreader

I've a project in Yii2 that using PHPExcel library for read an Excel file.
I've a **Transaction Id** column that contain data in *General* format cell.
Screenshoot of my Excel file: 
[image]

You can see above, if I input 15 characters of number and put two dots inside it. It will displayed as number.

***First Ex***: Input => 800.003.151476962 in cell showed as 
[image] 
and in **Formula Bar** showed as 
[image]

But if input 15 characters of number without dots inside, it will displayed as **Scientific Notation/Exponential**.

***Second Ex***: Input => 800003151476925 in cell showed as
[image] => **Scientific Notation/Exponential** data format
and in **Formula Bar** showed as
[image]

When I'm trying to read the data in my PHP, my PHP will read the ***Second Ex*** data as **Scientific Notation/Exponential** format not as string/number/decimal.

**How do I can get the *Second Ex* data as *800003151476925*(no matter string or number or decimal format) not *8.00003E+14* in my PHP?**

Thanks :)

**NOTE**: Actually I've read and try suggestion in [Convert exponential to a whole number in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964059/convert-exponential-to-a-whole-number-in-php), [Convert exponential number to decimal in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461444/convert-exponential-number-to-decimal-in-php), [Convert exponential number to decimal in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461444/convert-exponential-number-to-decimal-in-php) but I got nothing.

Answer (score 5):

If you put 2 dots (decimal points) in a value, then it can only be a string; so MS Excel will format it `General` (the default cell formatting for MS Excel) as a string. With a single dot (decimal point), PHPExcel will treat it as a number, and set the datatype accordingly; and MS Excel will see it as a floating point number, and MS Excel `General` formatting rules will format it using scientific formatting if it is greater than a standard 32-bit integer size, treating it as a float.

If you want to force string formatting, then you need to do so explicitly, either by setting it as a string datatype using `setCellValueExplicit()` to force it to be set as a string; or set a format mask other than `General` such as `0`

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A9')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(
        '0'
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge :) Doesn't the your code above only can use for write an Excel file?

Comment: If you're reading the value, then it's too large for an integer in 32-bit PHP, and will be displayed in scientific format anyway even with 64-bit PHP if you simply echo it (nothing to do with PHPExcel, just basic PHP). use PHP's `sprintf()` or `number_format()` functions to display it as an integer

Comment: Even though your suggestion did'n work for my case, at least I get new knowledge may be useful nexttime. Thanks :D
I've tried the to display as string using `sprintf` but it display the **8.00003E+14** as string, not **800003151476922** as string

Comment: FormatCode 0 just set it as Number and format it with "0" format. It shows as a Number not a Text in cell format panel in Excel.